# Making raster DEM from irregular points shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem

I assume that first I need to interpolate and then somehow turn it into raster in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

If the points has a field that represents elevation values, you need to interpolate the points to convert them to raster elevation. You can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html) on how to do that in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have column with elevation values for these points there are many ways to go depending on what is the nature of your data. You must decide what interpolation method you want to choose.

Do you have billions of points or just few? How are the points scattered - relatively regularly, dense in some parts and sparse in others? These are very important questions to ask for before choosing how to interpolate raster from the points.

QGIS has many tools for interpolations:

1. Interpolate raster directly from points using **Interpolation plugin** allowing to choose between **TIN** and **IDW** interpolation
2. Interpolate raster directly from points using **Processing toolbox** - there are many GRASS and SAGA geoalgorithms like **nearest neighbor, triangulation, idw, spline** (various versions)**, kriging** (various versions) etc.
3. Rasterize points and use some of interpolation or fill nulls algorithm for rasters no data values if any in **Processing toolbox**